# How to style graphviz terminal nodes only?

Tags: graphviz

I use the `targetIncludes` goal of the depgraph-maven-plugin to produce a dot file, and generate a graph.

When I configure the "dot" layout engine its obvious where the terminal nodes are - at the bottom of the diagram. But if I switch to the "fdp" layout its difficult to make them out.

How can I style/color these terminal nodes differently during the generation of the dot file? (obviously I could edit the dot file afterwards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't know about **depgraph-maven** capabilities).
The Graphviz language does not include any conditionals,  however it includes a pre-processor/post-processor language - **gvpr** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) that can easily color terminal nodes.
If you can produce output with format = **canon** or **dot** (https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/) then run that file through **gvpr** like so:

```
gvpr -c 'N{if($.indegree=="0"||$.outdegree=="0"){$.style="filled";$.color="red";};}' myoutputfile
```

Then run that file thru **fdp**, **neato**, **dot**, or whatever engine you like.